# Leave One Subject Out Cross Validation: mean vs median

Tags: machine-learning, classification, variance, cross-validation, bias

Assume we have a dataset with `n` subjects and `m` labels and train a classifier. To ensure that there is no subject bias in the training data, we perform Leave One Subject Out (LOSO) cross-validation.

Should we report the mean or the median performance metrics? It seems that most papers use the mean. But aren't there cases in which the median would be the better choice, e.g., if there are subjects in the dataset who only represent a small portion of the `m` labels or if there is a high inter-subject variance? Which would you prefer?

Comment: Yes, this could make sense. You can show both and you will quickly see if there is anything suspicious going on.

Comment: I don't fully understand your setup. So do you have several observations with potentially more than one class per subject? Can you maybe give an exemplary performance metric? As long as you're just counting misclassifications, a misclassification is a binary event and the median is not a good summary of those. A count is a sum of indicators, and the mean is just a "standardised sum".

Comment: Suppose one of your training models/hyperparameter choices has 60% correct classification on leave-one-out cross-validation and another 95%, is the median performance of both the same?

Comment: Assume we have `m` possible activity labels in the dataset. Each subject performs some of the activities, but not necessarily all of them. For instance, some subjects only perform `1` out of the `m` activities. Assume `s` is such a subject. The macro F1 score for `s` is 1 if all samples of `s` are classified correctly. But eve if 1 sample of `s` is misclassified, the macro F1 score drops to less than 0.5, right? Even though this is only 1 misclassification, it would heavily impact the average macro F1 score over all LOSO runs while the median would still be fine.